# How to display a specific column with the same ID in one row

Tags: select

I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone help to solve this?
This is my table looks like:

```
cusId   orderId  itemId
00006    00003    002
00006    00003    006
00007    00001    001
00007    00001    003
00007    00004    003
00008    00002    001
00008    00002    009
```

I want to display it as follows:

```
(002 006)
(001 003) (003)
(001 009)
```

which is each line represents a different cusId, then group the itemId into one bracket when the orderId is the same.

Should I code it in SQL or in Java? How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure which databse you are using but in MySQL you can do this:-

> SELECT
>
> group_concat("(",Items,")")  as cRows
>
> FROM
>
> (SELECT        group_concat(itemId) AS Items,          cusId       FROM testTable
>      GROUP BY orderId    ORDER BY cusId) AS cusTable
>
> GROUP BY cusTable.cusId;

Where testTable is your table as described in your question. Notice the use of a subquery in there and group_concat() doing most of the work here. No need to do anything in JAVA.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I just know got this group_concat in MySQL query. Learn one thing today!